# Using Application.FileDialog from a different VBA application

Tags: vba, office365

I'm using CAM software called AlphaCAM which has Visual Basic integrated into its software. I'm trying to run a button within a userform utilizing the file dialog object to return a folder path. However, it does not recognize the FileDialog object and I believe it is because I'm working outside of an office application. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command_FindFolder_Click()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim foldername As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    foldername = .SelectedItems(1)
End With 
NextCode:
    Set fldr = Nothing
    TB_FolderName.Value = foldername
End Sub
```

I've also tried changing the variable fldr to "Dim fldr As Object" but the code still trips on "Application.FileDialog".

Is there loop hole around this? Can I open an excel window just to run the file dialog?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Can I open an excel window just to run the file dialog?"

Yes you can:

```
Private Sub Command_FindFolder_Click()

    Dim fldr, xlApp
    Dim foldername

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set fldr = xlApp.FileDialog(4) 'msoFileDialogFolderPicker
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = xlApp.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show = -1 Then foldername = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With 

    Set fldr = Nothing
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    'TB_FolderName.Value = foldername
    WScript.Echo foldername

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is something like that:

```
Sub foo()
Dim shell: Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim file: Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)
BrowseForFile = file.self.Pat
End Sub
```